# how to delete what was allocated by std::to_string()?

Tags: c++, string, memory, valgrind, free

I have this function

```
string getLen(string str)
{
    return std::to_string(str.length());
}
```

then I have this generic function:

```
template<class T>
template<class Function>
SortedList<T> SortedList<T>::apply(Function function)
{
  SortedList<T> new_list=SortedList<T>();
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
      T object = function(*(data[i]));
      //some code
     
  }
  return new_list;
}
```

when function `getLen` is passed to function `apply` memory gets lost (this is what valgrind said)
so I want to delete the memory allocated by it but I don't know how

I tried

```
T object = function(*(data[i]));
delete object
```

which is wrong , then I tried

```
T object = function(*(data[i]));
delete &object
```

which is also wrong
valgrind Error:

```
 HEAP SUMMARY:
==7051==     in use at exit: 34 bytes in 2 blocks
==7051==   total heap usage: 66 allocs, 64 frees, 2,153 bytes allocated
==7051==
==7051== 26 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 2
==7051==    at 0x4C2A593: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:344)
==7051==    by 0x4EF4CD8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==7051==    by 0x403AFA: char* std::string::_S_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (basic_string.tcc:138)
==7051==    by 0x403A12: char* std::string::_S_construct_aux<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::__false_type) (basic_string.h:1725)
==7051==    by 0x403937: char* std::string::_S_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&) (basic_string.h:1746)
==7051==    by 0x403510: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&) (basic_string.tcc:229)
==7051==    by 0x402998: std::string __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<std::string, char>(int (*)(char*, unsigned long, char const*, __va_list_tag*), unsigned long, char const*, ...) (string_conversions.h:99)
==7051==    by 0x402629: std::to_string(unsigned long) (basic_string.h:2883)
==7051==    by 0x40191D: getLen(std::string) (part_a_test.cpp:17)
==7051==    by 0x403173: mtm::SortedList<std::string> mtm::SortedList<std::string>::apply<std::string (*)(std::string)>(std::string (*)(std::string)) (sortedList.h:209)
==7051==    by 0x402089: main (part_a_test.cpp:79)
==7051==
==7051== 34 (8 direct, 26 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==7051==    at 0x4C2A593: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:344)
==7051==    by 0x40326B: mtm::SortedList<std::string>::operator=(mtm::SortedList<std::string> const&) (sortedList.h:90)
```

a minimal reproducible example:
sortedList.h

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
template <class T>
 class SortedList
 {
  T** data;
  int size;
  int max_size;
  void expand();
  static const int EXPAND_RATE=2;
  static const int INITIAL_SIZE=10;
public: 

  SortedList();
 ~SortedList();
  SortedList(const SortedList&);
  SortedList& operator=(const SortedList& list);
  void insert(const T&);
 template<class Function>
  SortedList<T> apply(Function function);
};
template <class T>
SortedList<T>::SortedList():data(new T*[INITIAL_SIZE]),size(0),max_size(INITIAL_SIZE){}

template <class T>
SortedList<T>::~SortedList()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete data[i];
   }
    delete[] data;
}
template <class T>
SortedList<T>::SortedList(const SortedList<T>& list):
  data(new T*[list.max_size])
 ,size(list.size)
 ,max_size(list.max_size)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         T* new_element=new T(*(list.data[i]));
        data[i]=new_element;
     }
 }
template <class T>
SortedList<T>& SortedList<T>::operator=(const SortedList<T> &list)
{
     if(this==&list)
     {
         return *this;
     }
     T** data_temp;
     data_temp=new T*[list.size];
     for(int i=0;i<list.size;i++)
     {
         T* new_element=new T(*(list.data[i]));
        data_temp[i]=new_element;
     }
     for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
     {
         delete data[i];
     }
     delete[] data;
     data=data_temp;
     size=list.size;
     max_size=list.max_size;
     return *this;
}
template<class T>
void SortedList<T>::expand()
{
  int new_size = max_size * EXPAND_RATE;
  T** new_data = new T*[new_size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
  {
   *(new_data[i]) = *(data[i]);
  }
 delete[] data;
 data = new_data;
 max_size = new_size;
}
template <class T>
void SortedList<T>::insert(const T&object)
{
    
 if(size>=max_size)
 {
     expand();
 }
 int index=0;
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
     T* temp=data[i];
     T& x=*temp;
    
  if(x < object)
  {
    //std::cout<<"index is"<<x<<std::endl;
      if (i + 1 == size)
      {
          index = size;
      }
    continue;
  }
  index=i;
  break;
 }
 size++;
for (int i = size-1; i >index; i--)
 {
  data[i]=data[i-1]; 
 }
 
 T* item=new T(object);
 data[index]=item;
 
}
template<class T>
template<class Function>
SortedList<T> SortedList<T>::apply(Function function)
{
  SortedList<T> new_list=SortedList<T>();
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
      T object = function(*(data[i]));
      //some code

  }
  return new_list;
}
```

main.c

```
string getLen(string str)
{
    return std::to_string(str.length());
}
int main()
{
SortedList<string> lst1 = SortedList<string>();
    lst1.insert("Charlie");
    lst1.insert("Bob");
    lst1.insert("Alice");
    lst1.insert("Donald");

lst1 = lst1.apply(getLen);
}
```

Comment: You don't....  `to_string` returns an object, not a pointer. Nothing to delete.

Comment: Unrelated, `SortedList<T> new_list=SortedList<T>();` is redundant. Just use `SortedList<T> new_list;` . More typing != more better.

Comment: Why do you believe you have to deallocate something? Did you get any problems with that?

Comment: @ChrisMM I will add the valgrind error I get maybe you can help me understand it

Comment: I suspect the valgrind issue will be in `SortedList` related code. A proper [mcve] would go a *long* way in finding whatever the *real* problem is.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ because of what i got from valgrind can you see it please

Comment: You forgot the an important part of that valgrind error, btw. That leading `at` is preceded by the claim of what the problem actually is.

Comment: @WhozCraig I added the valgrind error

Comment: You left out the actual *error* part of the error. All you posted was the call stack of where the error claims to root.

Comment: @WhozCraig and now?

Comment: We need the entirety of your sorted list. I continue to suspect the error is there. It would be part of a proper [mcve], as I asked before.

Comment: Where is `toString` ? I don't see it used nor defined.

Comment: Impending doom approaching. Without a [mcve] this will be destined for closure. We're only lobbing wild guesses without it. This site isn't about guesses; it's about answers. *Please* provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: @WhozCraig I added it, it just took me some time to do so

Comment: @WhozCraig if i need to add anything else please tell me

Comment: @raghad Well, that starts here `mtm::SortedList<std::string> mtm::SortedList<std::string>` not at `stds::tring`, no? So I don't suspect that `std::string` leaks, but something's wrong with a `std::string` kept in `SortedList`, whatever that is.

Comment: @WhozCraig aaah sorry mtm is a namespace I forgot to delete it

Comment: @WhozCraig here, I deleted it

Comment: @TedLyngmo when I write it should I add the includes like `#include <string>` ??

Comment: @TedLyngmo I checked it now after I added one include and a using and it compiles

Comment: @WhozCraig it does compile now

Comment: I have an appt, so I won't be able to look at this more until later, but FYI, this is totally wrong in the `expand` member : `*(new_data[i]) = *(data[i]);`. That code assumes there are already concrete instances on *both* sides of the assignment operator; there isn't. In fact you just allocated a pointer bed for the left side. I'm *positive* that code is supposed to be `new_data[i] = data[i];` . The expanded list is supposed to take ownership of the objects in the old bed, and that means copying their pointers; not their values.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the valgrind output (using `valgrind  --show-error-list=yes --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all`) but it came back with no leaks at all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh then it means that the error came from somewhere else ...thanks for the help everyone